# Can I hide model properties from datasources in strongloop?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I would like to pass a "token" object to POST /MyObject. The easiest way to do that seems to be to add it as a property to MyObject.json. The problem is that this token is not persisted (it doesn't last for very long and there's no need to save it).

I figured out how to get around this issue for POST:

```
MyObject.beforeRemote('create', function (context, unused, nextFn) {
    var token = context.args.data.token;

    //We have to delete this so it doesn't try to put it in the database
    delete context.args.data.token;
    nextFn();
});
```

But the code crashes when I do a GET.

I tried just adding it as a second parameter to a new remote method, with MyObject as the first param, but after wrestling with strongloop for three hours and having nothing to show for it I gave up/

Is there any way to just add a property so that I can use it in node, but keep it from being persisted?

Comment: Why you should add to properties?? How is your remote method?

Comment: I need it because I'm using it to do extra work with a third-party library that needs that token. If the token is valid, I want to persist MyObject to the database, without the token.

I am adding it to the properties so that it shows up in the model schema for POST, since it's needed for that.

Comment: If you want to show in schema for documentation there is another ways. For example you can create some models without datasources just for representation for method schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a model just for representation.

```
//MyObjectInput.json
{
  "name": "MyObjectInput",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "token": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  ...
  },  
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}


//MyObject.json
{
  "name": "MyObject",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  ...
  },  
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Please note that to `sctrict` key in `MyObject.json`. It denotes all defined properties should be persisted. Now you don't have `token` in `MyObject` definition, so it's not persisted.

```
//MyObject.js
MyObject.remoteMethod(
        'create', {
            accepts: [
                {
                    arg: 'data',
                    type: 'MyObjectInput',
                    http: {source: 'body'}
                }
            ],
            returns: {
                arg: 'result',
                type: 'object',
                root: true
            },
            http: {
                path: "/create",
                verb: 'post',
                status: 201
            }
        }
    );
```